# Drupal 6 : how to display a node?

Tags: php, drupal-6, content-type, drupal-hooks

I'm currently developing a module for Drupal 6, in which I have created a custom content type.

I'm able to create/update/delete a node of this content type by using `hook_form`, `hook_insert` and so on.

Now what I want is displaying the node when I click on it in my content list (tab "view"). I don't understand how to do this. Currently Drupal only displays a double dash for the title and antoher one for the body.

I tried using `hook_view` and `hook_nodeapi` with `$op == 'view'`, but neither seem to work.

I think it must be a pretty basic thing, but I'm a Drupal noob and there are still a lot I don't understand about it.

Any hints would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, viewing the title and body of a custom content node should "just work" as if it were any other node. Assuming your nodes are being inserted and updated correctly, then something else is breaking the content on view. Problems in your templates perhaps? (Double-dashes make me think of HTML comments.)

If you have to modify the node to display custom fields, then `hook_view()` is the right place. Be sure to call `node_prepare()` before you make your modifications:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_view().
 */
function MODULE_view($node, $teaser = FALSE, $page = FALSE) {
  $node = node_prepare($node, $teaser);
  return $node;
}
```

Comment: You are perfectly right, the problem was in the page.tpl.php. I was so focused on the hooks thing that I didn't think of looking to the template files. Silly me! Thanks a lot scronide !